# rails_admin - how to sort by custom fields in list view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am using RoR 4.1 with RailsAdmin 0.6.8.  I can create custom fields in RA either by defining a method on the model and including it via

```
field :custom_method
```

or formatted_value

```
field :custom_field do
 formatted_value{ bindings[:object].something_here }
end
```

The problem is I cannot sort by that column in list view.  Anybody have experience with this?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Not really.  I solved some of the problems with counter_cache: true by simply storing the count of child records in parent column (instead of counting it live) but that does not work for everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
field :custom_field do
sortable :name #or:lastname or :firstname
formatted_value{ bindings[:object].something_here}
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO when answering it's best to add a description not just post the code.